# Express, EJS, challenge with testing for undefined

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm creating a simple website with nodejs using the express framework, couchdb for a database and EJS for templating.  There will be times when some of my fields are null or undefined in some of my JSON docs, and I need to handle that.

```
<% if (typeof test !== 'undefined') { %>
  <p><%= test %></p>
<% } %>
```

That bit of code seems to handle the 'test' field being undefined just fine, but the code below throws an error that says 'test is undefined'

```
<% if (test) { %>
  <p><%= test %></p>
<% } %>
```

Why doesn't javascript understand test to be undefined and then just put false in the if clause?

Comment: ... because its undefined not false :? I personally am happy its not like "oh hey bro you must of meant this undefined to be false"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the concept of "undefined" is different than the state of a variable being defined in the JavaScript language.  The reasons for this are understandable but the effects can be confusing, especially regarding variable names vs object properties.

You have demonstrated how trying to access an undefined variable will throw an exception.  Don't confuse this state (a variable is not defined) with the "undefined" type:

```javascript
if (bogusVariable) { // throws ReferenceError: bogusVariable is not defined.
typeof(bogusVariable); // => undefined - wow, that's confusing.
```

However, properties of objects which are not defined can be tested safely:

```javascript
var x = {}; // an object
x.foo; // => undefined - since "x" has no property "foo".
typeof(x.foo); // => undefined
if (!x.foo) { /* true */ }
```

You could take advantage of this property by noting that all variables are actually properties of the "global" object (either "global" or "window", in web browsers).

```javascript
bogus; // => ReferenceError: bogus is not defined.
global.bogus; // => undefined (on node/rhino)
window.bogus; // => undefined (on web browsers)
```

So you might be able to write your EJS code as such:

```
<% if (global.test) { %>
  <p><%= test %></p>
<% } %>
```

Yes, it's confusing, as are many parts of the JavaScript language.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, my problem was actually not in JavaScript.  The js was just fine, the error was coming from within express, the variable didn't exist there.  The variable was just fine in the template, so express's render function was dumping that error.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the last piece if code from your answer with testing `if(global.test)` doesn't work for me. It always throws exception. I had to check it with `if( typeof( global.text) !== 'undefined')`.

Comment: in ejs, you can use `locals.test` when you want to use a variable (here test) who may not be defined.

Answer (score 4):

most languages are like this:

```
  irb
  >> foo
  NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem was actually not in JavaScript. The js was just fine, the error was coming from within express, the variable didn't exist there. The variable was just fine in the template, so express's render function was dumping that error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To check if test is defined, you need to do that:

```
<% if (this.test) { %>
   here, test is defined
<% } %>
```